How to make Wordpress ignore GET parameters when caching pages?
Situation: there is a WordPress site, a small article-based site. It loads not very quickly (500-600ms), but with caching, the values are much better (20-30ms). The problem arises when accessing a page like http://example.com/page?foo=12345 - pages with GET parameters, although cached by most popular plugins, are still considered unique, even though the page doesn't actually respond to GET parameters. There is a concern that an attacker could DDoS the site with requests like ?foo=1 + ?foo=2 + ?foo=3, etc.
Question - what is the best way to avoid this? Drop GET parameters, find a slightly less popular caching plugin that accounts for this, use object caching, etc.?
I've already tried to redirect pages index.php?foo=123 to index.php via WP-hooks and via Yoast SEO plugin Also, I've tried to cache DB objects via redis
Obv, I've tried WP Super Cache and W3 Total Cache, but as I mentioned earlier, they consider that king of pages distinct, so third request would create third cache entry, that won't help

For WP Super Cache, it's not well documented, but there appear to be two ways to accomplish this.

Ignore ALL $_GET parameters: Under Wp Super Cache Settings > Advanced, there is a checkbox labeled "Don’t cache pages with GET parameters. (?x=y at the end of a url)". This would mean that any URL would be treated as not having query parameters at all.
Tracking Parameters: On the same page, near the bottom, there is a form section labeled "Tracking Parameters". It reads "This setting allows the plugin to ignore those parameters and show an already cached page." This should allow you to specify specific parameters to ignore.


Your point 1 doesn't work the way you're thinking; instead it means that any page with GET parameters added to it (?x=y) will not be cached, but will instead be regenerated every time it's hit. This is the opposite of the OP's request. Unchecking that box will mean that pages with GET parameters will be cached.

Although, this comment might be useful in analysis of plugin performance and its GET-params related options, that option still doesn't allow to fully disable ALL GET-params. Now I even find this kinda logical. So the actual answer to my question in its original form is "It is impossible, but there is some hints"
Anyway, thank you!

Sure thing. I realize option #1 isn't exactly what the OP was looking for, but I'm pretty sure option #2 IS. "Tracking parameters" allows you to exclude individual parameters from being used for caching.

Use this-
function wpse425571_ignore_get_parameters() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Only apply on frontend
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        $uri = strtok( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' );
        if ( ! empty( $uri ) ) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $uri;
        }
    }

    // Ensure query parameters are ignored
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '';
    }

    // Remove query parameters from superglobals
    $_GET = array();
    $_REQUEST = array();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse425571_ignore_get_parameters' );

This code snippet ensures that any GET parameters are ignored when caching pages by modifying the $_SERVER variables and superglobals early in the request cycle. This prevents the caching plugins from treating pages with different GET parameters as unique pages.

Doesn't work, even if I try to move it from 'init' to earlier steps plugins_loaded or muplugins_loaded - both plugins (W3 Total Cache and WP Super Cache) somehow just ignore that kind of modification
